# I need help to understand an unconfirmed transaction and 'bitcoin language'

Tags: blockchain

I've had a transaction that is 58 hours home. Trough browsing this website I looke at the lock time of mine 497931 and the current lockheight is 498298. Can anyone help? Will it be done soon? I was worried there was issues with the recipient.

https://blockexplorer.com/tx/67ba33a7756226835f66d07618ffb9fa868bf05ee25b70bf9f0e2371ef1f560f

I used block explorer as someone here said it was most up to date. It also says n/a next to minining, so I'm guessing it just hasnt been mined yet and there is congestion

I need help understanding the bitcoin lanuage on these sites. The other link doesnt really answer my question

Comment: for example; does the unconfirmed block mean its still in the 'mempool''.... or does the loctime mean its in a block?

Comment: The locktime defines the earliest block the tx is allowed to be confirmed in. We're now past the locktime, so it can be confirmed in a block. Your tx is still in the mempool, it will hang out there until a miner confirms it. No need to worry, the network is just very congested due to high tx volumes.

Comment: thank you very much, I've been trying to work it out myself but I dont think I can earn everything in 24hour crash course!

Comment: ok so now it says removed/double spends so I've contacted my sender as I didnt do anything to it!